# Wikipedia Mediawiki API get URL in query

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Using the MediaWiki API I have a query that returns the results I want:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Apple&aplimit=5
```

**How can I modify it to also include the URL for each of the pages that are returned?**

I tried adding the "info" property and "url" info, but it does not return additional information:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Apple&aplimit=5&prop=info&inprop=url
```

Comment: why not use instead Wikidata Query Service? https://query.wikidata.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the parameters you use to get the result to a `generator` instead of a list and then use `prop=info` and `inprop=url` in the query. Like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=info&generator=allpages&inprop=url&gapfrom=Apple&gaplimit=5